# c++ nuget packages for opengl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, nuget

I try to include opengl via nuget.

This is my packages.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <package id="boost" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="Native" />
    <package id="boost_atomic-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_chrono-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_date_time-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_filesystem-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_log_setup-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_log-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_system-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_thread-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="boost_unit_test_framework-vc140" version="1.64.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="glew.v140" version="1.12.0" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="glfw" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="glfw.redist" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="GLMathematics" version="0.9.5.4" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="lua" version="5.3.3" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="lua.redist" version="5.3.3" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="nupengl.core" version="0.1.0.1" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="nupengl.core.redist" version="0.1.0.1" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="sdl2" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="sdl2.redist" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="turtle" version="1.2.6" targetFramework="native" />
    <package id="unofficial.flayan.glm" version="0.9.8.4" targetFramework="Native" />
  </packages>
```

It should contain all I need however i am getting an error:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawElements@16
```

I can "fix" that by including `opengl32.lib`.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
```

But I wonder if I am missing something in my packages. I was under the impression that one just adds the packages and they include the libraries into the build.

Am I misusing nuget, is there something else I should have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I misusing nuget, is there something else I should have done?

No, do not need to do anything else but just including the `opengl32.lib`.
`glDrawElements` is a "core" OpenGL feature. This function resides in opengl32.dll, which you unfortunately forgot to include in your linking libs.

Besides, Some libraries support auto-linking mechanism (for example, freeglut), that is, the header file contains a line like #prgama comment(lib, "lib1_name.lib").

To resolve that LNK error, just include the `opengl32.lib` by the syntax：

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
```